# How to empty "Pictures, videos" folder?

Tags: insufficient-memory, lg

I have a LG F60 phone, it has only 1gb of internal storage, and I can't find a way to empty the "Pictures, videos" folder.

Any help?

[image]

The pictures and videos I want to keep are already backed-up in Google Photos. I have the regular 'File Manager' that comes with the phone. If I browse the folder I only see the files in the external storage and what I want is to delete all the pictures and videos from the internal storage.

**Regular File Manager**

[image]

**Regular File Manager**

[image]

I go to images and as you can see most of the folders are in the external memory... the thing is that I can't access that 'storage/emulated' folder..

[image]
[image]

If I go to videos folder, all external.
[image]

And if I go to 'All files', Internal I see this 'storage/emulated' folder which I can't access..
[image]
[image]

Comment: @beeshyams I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: `/storage/emulated` is not a physical directory. Once you remove from internal storage using solid explorer, you will find space freed up. As to why you file manager can't see internal storage it can be a separate question

Comment: If you are sure everything is backed up to Google Photos, you can free up the from Google Photos app itself. It deletes the files physically from SD card or internal memory.

Comment: @MAN I get this message 'no items to remove from device'

Comment: Download Total Commander and than try.

Answer (score 0):

Your device should be having an inbuilt file manager, if it doesn't you can download from Play Store. Many are available. [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) is a good one. Photos are stored in `/sd/DCIM` or if you have downloaded videos/ photos, they would be in `/sd/downloads`. You will need to search for the location and delete them, if stored elsewhere

If you don't wish to identify the folders, use Solid Explorer, on launching the application , tap the menu button on left and scroll down where you will find *photos* and *videos* folder. Browse through them, select and delete

[image]

Alternatively, [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) gives a good visual feedback of your storage and let's you select the file you wish to and delete

[image]

Comment: HI thanks for you answer! What I want to delete is all the pictures and videos that are in the internal storage, no need to worry about the SD card.

Comment: I'll try with solid explorer and come back .

Comment: Just go ahead and do that using solid explorer as explained. Also please see my comment under your question about emulated. That is not real in the sense not occupying physical memory

Comment: Haven't seen any response? Any problems?

Comment: @beeshams Hi there, I was quite busy. I'm still unable to empty that 'Pictures, videos' folder, and its size is increasing. I'm trying with DiskUsage, and managed to delete some of this files (screenshots, and Telegram images), but I still got 76MB of thumbnails and can't access them. I get this message 'no viewer found' while trying to go to those files through DiskUsage.